# Change summary when returning from nested PreferenceScreen

Tags: android

I have a PreferencesActivity with a nested PreferenceScreen, so the PreferenceScreen has its own line in the list of preferences, and when you click on it, you're presented with a few more options.

When the user changes one of those options, I update that option's summary to show what the user has selected.

I also want to change the summary of the PreferenceScreen on the main list to show the values of its sub-settings. I'm using an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener to update both summaries at once. However, only the summary of the preference gets changed, not the summary of the preference screen.

Here is simplified code:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (key.equals(SUB_PREFERENCE)){
        updateSubPreferenceSummary(); //works
        updatePreferenceScreenSummary(); //doesn't work
    } else if (key.equals(SOME_OTHER_PREF_IN_ROOT_OF_PREFERENCEACTIVITY) {
        updatePreferenceScreenSummary(); //works. (not what I want--just illustrating issue)
    }
}
```

My theory is that Android is ignoring the first screen when it's not visible, so it doesn't get updated.  I tried overriding onBackPressed(), but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work-around. Apparently, the summary was getting updated, but the view from the parent screen was not getting invalidated/redrawn.

So I do this after updating the summary:

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){onContentChanged();
        }});
```

I put it in the Handler just as a precaution, because I'm not sure what thread the onSharedPreferenceChanged() gets called from.